# Github: Fork or create a brand new Repository?

Tags: github, language-agnostic, refactoring, git-fork

I'm making major changes to a github project, almost rewriting it from scratch, and want to share my contribution. Should I always use fork or does it may make sense to create a new repository?

More details: I'm rewriting from Winforms to WPF a project that is completely abandoned. It was an old sample from Microsoft, and someone just copied it to github, identical code without any improvement. There are about 5 forks, all irrelevant, and only 1 commit (irrelevant) made in the last 12 months.

Does it make sense that I create a brand new repository for that? Forking from the old repository would give any benefit to someone or will only confuse people? Also, would it be ethical if I change the namespace?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For a complete rewrite of an old GitHub repo, a fork does not make sense.
Forking means contributing back to the original project through Pull Requests.

A new repo (and new namespace) which mentions clearly in its `README` its origin is simpler, and clearer.